# How to auto-break or paginate HTML so that generated PDF looks the same as paginated HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, pagination

I have a requirement to `auto-break` or `paginate` HTML content, so that the generated PDF looks the same as the HTML.

**Requirement:** when HTML content overflows `A4` size paper then it must add a new page.

**Question:** when content overflows `A4` size paper it must generate a new page using any pdf-generating vue plugin, here I'm using `vue-html2pdf`.

**Re-producing steps:**

1. click on the `Auto add textcontent` button will generate multiple text lines and pages but pagination is not working;
2. then click on the `Generate pdf`  button will generate a PDF with pagination; I want this pagination automatically without generating PDF.

Here is what I have tried [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/page-break-v2lhqw?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

By adding an additional HTML element with `html2pdf__page-break` class will add a page break after that element. For example,

```
<div class="html2pdf__page-break"/>
```

In this case any elements after the above `<div>` will go to the next page. Such approach can still be used with the automatic pagination of the package, not just when the prop `manual-pagination` is enabled.

It is also recommended to divide the `pdf-content` section into multiple `pdf-item` sub sections. For example,

```
<section slot="pdf-content">
    <section class="pdf-item">
        <h4>Your Title</h4>
        <span>
            Some copy...
        </span>
    </section>

    <div class="html2pdf__page-break"/>

    <section class="pdf-item">
        <span>
            Some text...
        </span>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you for the solution,but i know this solution but the question is how to do it dynamically when text are added.

Comment: You can parse your text when it changes and split into more or less equal pdf-item sections (say check on a number of words) separated by the page-break element.